# How did Roger Douglas convince the labour party to carry a liberal economic reform?

Tags: economy, history, liberalism, labour-party, new-zealand

Roger Douglas the Minister of Finance of New Zealand from 1984-1988 made a huge liberal economic reform in his era (reducing the size of the state) it was so famous it was called "Rogernomics", but he did it in a left-wing party called labour party.

The BIG question is how did he convince president David Lange, a left-wing president, to allow him to do the Rogernomics reform being that what he thought was completely opposite of the left-wing ideology? How did he make that happen?